# How can my app be opened to a specific view with URL scheme?

Tags: ios, swift3, viewcontroller, url-scheme

I'd like to let another app open mine to a specific view using URL scheme. 
I've actually no idea how to handle this.

Does anyone have an idea?
Does something like `MyApp://MyViewController` can work directly or does I have to do something else?

Comment: Look up Deep Linking - this can definitely be done and is actually a very common practice. Handling the deep links in your AppDelegate will allow you to set specific views when the app is opened through your URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

From one application you can use the `canOpenUrl` function to open your app:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: “yourApp://?\test=test”) ,
 UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
             UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                 print("\n App opended")
             })
         }
         else{
             print("\n Can't open app")
         }
```

And in your application you would perform the handling in your `AppDelegate` in this function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options;
```